# how to abandon commits of certain characteristic when using git?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history, git-history-graph

for example i want to abandon all commits whose commit message is "temp commit", that is if the original commit history is as follows:

```
    X1 - X2 - X4 -X7 - .... Xn-2 -  Xn-1 - Xn
       \_ X3 -X5 - ..
             \_ X6 - X8  ..


    and x4 "temp commit"
    X6 "temp commit"
    Xn-1 "temp commit"
```

then the commit history will rewritten as follows, that is the commits x4, x6 and xn-1 are abandoned.

if a repo have totally 2000 commits, and 500 of the commits whose message is "temp commit", then the 500 commits will be abandoned, and only 1500 commits remains, how to do this git history rewritten?

i know it may have something to do with filter-branch, i know how to remove a folder using --tree-index, but how to remove commits of certain characteristic?

```
    X1 - X2 -X7 - .... Xn-2 - Xn
       \_ X3 -X5 - ..
             \_  X8  ..
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), I would try (but I have not tested that)

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    MSG=$(git log --format=%B -n 1 $GIT_COMMIT)
    if [ "$MSG" = "temp commit" ];
    then
        skip_commit "$@";
    else
        git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' HEAD
```

The function skip_commit is defined as follows, export it or put it in your .bashrc

```
skip_commit()
{
    shift;
    while [ -n "$1" ];
    do
        shift;
        map "$1";
        shift;
    done;
}
```

I'm unsure if that works for the whole repository or only one branch.

Comment: should this be written in a script file, it's difficult to write all this to the command line

Comment: Yes, probably, I only took the example from the link and modified it slightly (remove commits from an author).

Comment: @hugemeow In any case, you can at least copy-and-paste it.